# Discord py - creating my own music bot - error code

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Hey guys,**

I am trying to create my own music bot right now.

But I have some problems and I hope you can help me :)

**What does my code look like:**

```py
from discord import Game, Intents
from discord.ext import commands
from os import environ, listdir

from pafy import new
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio

import asyncio
import urllib.parse, urllib.request, re

intents = Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot is ready to go!')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    ffmpeg_opts = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("**Please connect to a voice channel!**")
        return
    
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = await channel.connect()
        
    await ctx.send(f':pushpin: Music bot connected to {channel}\n:mag_right: **Searching for** ``' + url + "``")
    video = new(url)
    audio = video.getbestaudio().url
    voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(audio, **ffmpeg_opts))
    voice.is_playing()

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):

    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel!")
        return
    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await ctx.send(f'Connected to ``{channel}``')

    await channel.connect()

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    user = ctx.message.author.mention
    await voice_client.disconnect()
    await ctx.send(f'Disconnected from {user}')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

**So now I got two major problems:**

- Youtube-dl isnt supported anymore so I switched to pafy

but I still get this error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OSError: ERROR: Unable to extract JS player URL; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

*The funny thing is that I dont get this error everytime I use the bot :(*

and the second problem is that I need to disconnect the bot everytime I want to chnage the song.

**How can I use somenthing like a queue? - I dont want to disconnect the bot everytime...**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all uninstall youtube-dl:

```
pip uninstall youtube-dl
```

Now how I did it:

There's a new Youtube-dl on Github

- https://github.com/l1ving/youtube-dl

If you are on Windows install it with this command:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/l1ving/youtube-dl
```

And you are done - sometimes I get an error like

> ERROR: Unable to extract JS player URL

but if this happens you just need to restart the bot and it should work again

Answer (score 0):

youtube-dl is no longer a thing. For alternative i would recommend using [lavalink](https://github.com/Frederikam/Lavalink) with [wavelink](https://github.com/PythonistaGuild/Wavelink) library. It got much more functionality.